# Subset of a table based on another table

Tags: python, dataframe, subset

I have the following data:

```
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['d1','d1','d2','d1'],'id1': ['Apple', 'Pear','Pear','Pear'], 'id2': ['Blue', 'Orange','Blue','Orange']})   
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['Apple','Pear'], 'id2': ['Orange', 'Orange']})
```

I did the following to get my result but I am not satisfied with the code:

```
t1['pairing'] = t1.apply(lambda x: "%s_%s" % (x.id1, x.id2), axis=1)
 
t2['pairing'] = t2.apply(lambda x: "%s_%s" % (x.id1, x.id2), axis=1)
 
(t1[t1.pairing.isin(t2.pairing)]).drop("pairing",axis=1)
```

Basically I want to keep in t1 the observations with a combination of id1 and id2 that is present in t2. A given combination can appears multiple times in t1 but only appears once in t2.

Thank you = )

Comment: Could you esplain a bit more the expected result? it doesn't seem clear enough to me

Comment: I edited it with my current non elegant solution. Lmk if it’s more clear

Comment: `t2.pairing.u` gives an error here. What does `u` represent?

Comment: Typos sorry I have to type with my phone :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
mask = t1.apply(lambda row: (row['id1'], row['id2']) in zip(t2.id1, t2.id2), axis=1)
result = t1[mask]
```

I'm not sure in what direction you want to write a "better" code snippet, but I personally would not create those string columns since all the information is already in the dataframe. That might be a criteria that you might like for yourself...

Comment: I like it better than my solution.  Thank you Do you know if there is a merge or join sql-like way of doing it?